# C# How to use FTP upload File Class

Tags: c#, ftp, upload

Sorry in advance for the stupid question. I have some questions about uploading files using FTP on C# that i need guidance:

```
 public void UploadFile(string FullPathFilename)
 {
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FullPathFilename);

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + filename);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);

    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(FullPathFilename);
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());

    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    response.Close();
    requestStream.Close();
    sourceStream.Close();
 }
```

So, I don't need to create a new folder, what do I substitute the [FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + filename);] with? Is this creating a folder in the remote ftp site?
    I am using this code inside a FTP class and I already have the files created and popuplated. How do I call this in my Program.cs to upload the files to the FTP directory?

Comment: `WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + filename)` does not create new folder. It creates `WebRequest` class instance that has parameter set to `_remoteHost + filename` value. This is the file name on the server to be uploaded actually. You should call it like `UploadFile(file2upload)` where `file2upload` is string parameter with file name to be uploaded (like `c:\temp\filetoupload.txt`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL has this format:

```
WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/directory/filename.ext");
```